# Setting up NDK Development in Android Studio 1.5

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, android-ndk

Is it possible to do Android NDK Development in Android Studio 1.5 , or is it best to use Eclipse for NDK Development?

Please can you advise me how I should setup Android Studio 1.5 IDE and how I should setup my Android Studio 1.5 project?

Currently, I have my Eclipse (Mars.1) IDE setup as follows **:**-

```
Window -> Preferences -> Android -> SDK Location -> [SDK directory]

Window -> Preferences -> Android -> NDK -> NDK Location -> [NDK directory]
```

I have my Eclipse project setup as follows **:**-

1. Inside Package Explorer , inside the project , I have a "jni" folder, which contains the C files and "Android.mk" files.
2. I build the C files by running "ndk-build" from inside the "jni" directory from Cygwin prompt
3. Inside the MainActivity.java , I have a static block which contains System.loadLibrary("nativeLibrary")

Please can you advise me how I should setup Android Studio 1.5 IDE for NDK Development and how I should setup my Android Studio 1.5 project?

Or is is best to use Eclipse for NDK Development?

Thank you for your expertise,
Best regards,
James

Comment: Have a look at this blog post: http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/new-gradle-build-tools-with-gradle-2.5/en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside project structure of Android Studio, you can set the NDK location (if not already) like so:
[image: Project Structure]